# why is function not applying to dataframe? Series object has no attribute called query (Pandas)

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe, data-science

I have a dataframe user and calls where common column is user_id. I need to drop values in user dataframe where churn is not null and remove those user_id rows in calls.

```
users = user_id,first_name,last_name,age,city,reg_date,plan,churn_date
1000,Anamaria,Bauer,45,"Atlanta-Sandy Springs-Roswell, GA MSA",2018-12-24,ultimate,
1001,Mickey,Wilkerson,28,"Seattle-Tacoma-Bellevue, WA MSA",2018-08-13,surf,
1002,Carlee,Hoffman,36,"Las Vegas-Henderson-Paradise, NV MSA",2018-10-21,surf,
1003,Reynaldo,Jenkins,52,"Tulsa, OK MSA",2018-01-28,surf,
1004,Leonila,Thompson,40,"Seattle-Tacoma-Bellevue, WA MSA",2018-05-23,surf,
1005,Livia,Shields,31,"Dallas-Fort Worth-Arlington, TX MSA",2018-11-29,surf,
1007,Eusebio,Welch,42,"Grand Rapids-Kentwood, MI MSA",2018-07-11,surf,
1008,Emely,Hoffman,53,"Orlando-Kissimmee-Sanford, FL MSA",2018-08-03,ultimate,
1009,Gerry,Little,19,"San Jose-Sunnyvale-Santa Clara, CA MSA",2018-04-22,surf,
1010,Wilber,Blair,52,"Dallas-Fort Worth-Arlington, TX MSA",2018-03-09,surf,
```

```
calls = id,user_id,call_date,duration
1000_93,1000,2018-12-27,8.52
1000_145,1000,2018-12-27,13.66
1000_247,1000,2018-12-27,14.48
1000_309,1000,2018-12-28,5.76
1000_380,1000,2018-12-30,4.22
1000_388,1000,2018-12-31,2.2
1000_510,1000,2018-12-27,5.75
1000_521,1000,2018-12-28,14.18
1000_530,1000,2018-12-28,5.77
1000_544,1000,2018-12-26,4.4
```

```
filter_user = users[users['churn_date'].notnull()]["user_id"].tolist()
```

I am creating a function to use list of user_id's from filter_user

```
def new(df):
    df = df.query('user_id != @filter_user')
    return df
```

I want to apply other dataframe and remove rows containing user_ids from filter_user and that is why applying the above function to other dataframe

```
calls.apply(new,axis=1)
```

AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'query'
Why is this error coming?

Answer (score 1):

When you running `calls.apply(some_action, axis=1)`, it would call function `some_action` to all rows of your dataframe `calls`.

So you should either change your `new` function to work with `pd.Series` of rows, either filter users using anohter techniques. The easiest way to do this, use [`df.isin()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.isin.html) method:

```py
df = df[ df.user_id.isin(filter_user ) ]
```

`df.isin` used to check whether each element in the DataFrame is contained in values.

Comment: Will i need to do this for every dataframe individually? Or is there a faster way of doing it for a list of dataframes

Comment: Do you have multiple dataframes with the same structure and the same user_id's? If it is, you can make function, that would first create `filter_user` list and then filter dataframe

Comment: I have several dataframes with the same structure. I am not able to write a function. I want a function actually. 
`users = users[~users.user_id.isin(filter_user)]
calls = calls[~calls.user_id.isin(filter_user)]
messages = messages[~messages.user_id.isin(filter_user)]
internet = internet[~internet.user_id.isin(filter_user)]`

Comment: If you want to use the same filter_user for every dataframe you can write something like this: `def filter_df (df): df = df [df.user_id.isin (filter_user)]`. But if all that you need is to filter this users, it can be done without a function, exactly as you wrote.

Comment: I wrote the function mentioned by you and I got the same attribute error mentioned above in the question

Comment: In order to apply the filter, you need to call the function as follows:
`users = filter_df(users)`
`calls = filter_df(calls)` etc

Comment: That doesn't work since dataframe object is not callable

Comment: What does type(filted_df) returns? Can you create another function `def remove_users(df): return df [df.user_id.isin (filter_user)]` and then call it `users = remove_users(users)`. Will there be the same error? I should note that I made small mistake above (forgot to return the value from a filter_df function), but it shouldn't lead to any errors.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```py
users_to_remove = users.loc[users.churn_date.notnull(), 'user_id']
filtered_calls = calls[~calls.user_id.isin(users_to_remove)]
```